# How does one setup default programs for users on terminal servers using a login script.

Tags: login-script, terminal-services, default-programs

Right now I have the default programs setup correctly but occasionally I am seeing users some how changing the defaults even though they do not have permissions. I can see they changed them by looking at their profile.  My guess is they are opening a file and getting hit with the windows prompt to chose a default. To get around this I am thinking of setting the default programs in the log in script to ensure they are set. Any help is appreciated. I should point out that most of my users are using PNG, JPG, DOCX, and the rest of the normal image and document file types. I am currently using FoxIt, Irfanview, Wordpad, ect.

Comment: Is it a domain environment?  I know you can accomplish this using group policy in a domain.

Comment: Ok so it is a domain environment. We have FoxIt setup in group policy. Now the we are looking to identify the registry keys that control file associations so we can use those keys in the log in script.